# 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed a project on codeigniter a php framework. It's working perfectly on my localhost where xampp is running. I have uploaded my whole project in the "wwwroot" folder and I can only get my opening page. But when I try to click on any link I get:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable..

Here is my websiter link:
Link : http://www.iimkondigre.in/
Problem Link : http://www.iimkondigre.in/course_archive

is my .htaccess file:

---

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|fonts|prototype|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|webservices)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Comment: you have to set  your basepath in config file like : http://www.iimkondigre.in/course_archive

Comment: you need to add index.php in tour path see here : http://www.iimkondigre.in/index.php/course_archive

Comment: you meen on base url ??  is my config.php $config['base_url'] = 'http://iimkondigre.in/';

Comment: you need to add htaccess rool for that.

Comment: sorry but i am not understand your ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It.

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
to
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. 
Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"

by

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

> .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

> For Windows server
>   `Web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule"> 
                    <match url="^(.*)$" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" /> 
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: is it right my base_url in config.php???               $config['base_url'] = 'http://iimkondigre.in/';

Comment: I have one doute is their this error depend on hosting OS like Linux & Windows??  In one project i will use codeignietr and use linux server is thier all work properlly, and i think now for this project i am use windows so is error?

Comment: No, this issue is related to .htaccess url rewriting.

Comment: Then what i do?? please

Comment: I am give all static pages link like ' iimkondigre.in/index.php/course_archive ' and is work well. But their is problem for dynamic page like contact us page

Comment: Ask your support  they allow .htaccess or not

Comment: supporter means to hosting company??

Comment: Yes, where you host site.

Comment: I will try this project on linux hosting and is work on it properlly, but is not on windows.

Comment: See my updated Ans.
see link:  http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: Yes problem solve, by your above link, i am add Web.config on index.php path, thanks. but their is no feedback data save in database. their is data retrive from database but not inserted.And file also not upload.

Comment: their is insert data is blank and I find this log **Status Code:
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently**

Comment: Any solution for this problem??

Answer (score 0):

The Only solution i came across till now is replacing

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("abc"); ?>">click here</a>
```

with

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("abc"); ?>">click here</a>
```

Comment: Is not work,Their is any file where we need  set site_url() ??

Answer (score 0):

As the above answered mention...
Just you have to change the " .htaccess " code as below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and create one file with name "web.config" and keep it in root directory these are windows server settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule"> 
                    <match url="^(.*)$" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" /> 
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```